# How do I type β with combining circumflex accent?

Tags: keyboard, unicode, input-method

There's combining circumflex accent, U+0302 (in the *Combining diacritical marks* block). Neither it nor the letter β are on my keyboard.

How do I combine the two to write "beta hat" like this when I can't use TeX?

[image: y = alpha-hat + beta-hat x]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Character Map, you can type (or paste) the letter β into the input field at the bottom and then double click the combining character.

> β̂

However, you can pretty much assume that this won't get rendered correctly. It looks good in Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

having added the beta and hat using character map if you insert a fullstop immediately after the hat it moves to the top of the letter avoiding the normal misalignment - you are then free to remove the full stop too.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using

<kbd><dead_greek></kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> followed by <kbd>ˆ</kbd>

This requires you have a `<dead_greek>` key set up (see https://superuser.com/questions/28932/how-do-i-input-greek-characters-in-ubuntu#29262).

It also requires that you have your keyboard layout set to *English (US, international AltGr Unicode combining)*

Answer (score 0):

To type `$\hat_\beta$` using Unicode characters: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> then its Unicode codepoint: [3B2](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=03B2) for greek Beta, then C-S-u [302](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0302) for the circumflex: **β̂** (it is not rendered correctly, the hat should be on top).

Comment: In the code of your answer you have misspelled the </kbd> close tag, hence it is not being displayed as you originally intended. Please edit it.

Comment: @AbhayPatil: thanks, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are typing an equation then
Go to Insert > Equation
In the equation box type \beta and give spacebar to get the beta symbol
No select beta symbol under the Equation tab > accents > hat
The beta symbol with hat will be in italics you just have to select the symbol with hat and remove italics